# Confidence interval when rolling a dice

Tags: statistics, dice, confidence-interval

If you roll a die 20,000 times and from these rolls you get either a 1,2, or 3  11,000 times, how can you calculate the confidence interval at 95% for the probability to get a 1,2, or 3?

The probability for each of the numbers is 1/6, and the the critical value for 95% is 1,96. But I don't know how to calculate the confidence interval.

Any hints, please

Thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you throwing one die or a pair of dice?  If only one, then the probability for each number is $\frac 16$, not $\frac 1{36}$ (assuming it's a fair die, of course).  If it's a pair of dice then you can't throw a $1$ (and a $2$ is less likely than a $3$).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1/6. I've edited the question

Comment: Got it.    In that case Hint:  If the die is fair then there is a $\frac 12$ probability of getting one of those numbers, hence this is akin to the toss of a fair coin.  You can do it exactly using the binomial distribution (though the numbers get gruesome).  Given the huge number of rolls I would advise using the normal approximation.

Comment: I don't see how it would be 1/2 for each of the numbers. The normal approximation is what I was thinking also, but how do I get to calculate it?

Comment: It isn't $\frac 12$ for each of the numbers, it's $\frac 12$ that the number is one of $1,2,3$.  (there are only six possibilities and you have named three of them).  To do the normal:  the mean would be $10000$ and the standard deviation would be  about $70.71$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Of course. Good, good. Okay, I have something to start with. Many thanks lulu.